# How to use MSMAPI32.ocx in WPF to send mail?

Tags: c#, wpf, activex

We are developing an desktop application based on WPF, which has a feature that user can send feedback to us. We can receive the Name, Email, Body and so on.

For some historical problems we used **MSMAPI** to help us send mail, as time goes on we found all its function work very well *until we did tests on clean machine*.

The ActiveX control said, **please offer me a license so I can move on**, well that's make us quite confused, because that control doesn't have license at all.

Ok, I will talk about the detail now.

In folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (On Win7 x64), we have `msmapi32.ocx`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), we have to wrapper it so can be host on a Windows Form. We did it, and got two assemblies: `MSMAPI.dll` and `AxMSMAPI.dll`, so we make our application reference these two DLLs.

Here is our code(XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ax="clr-namespace:AxMSMAPI;assembly=AxMSMAPI"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <StackPanel>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <ax:AxMAPIMessages Name="axMAPIMessage" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <ax:AxMAPISession Name="axMAPISession" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Ofcourse, we have to **change our project build target to X86**, otherwise it would throw ClassNotDefined exception. Pretty well, press F5, the main window shows successfully.

Then we copy the Debug folder of our demo application, double click, Oops... It said, *WpfAPplication14 has stopped work*. We captured the exption, here is the stack:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message='Initialization of 'AxMSMAPI.AxMAPIMessages' threw an exception.' Line number '-' and line position '-'.
  HResult=-2146233087
  IsTransient=false
  Message='Initialization of 'AxMSMAPI.AxMAPIMessages' threw an exception.' Line number '-' and line position '-'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=-
  LinePosition=-
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.ComponentModel.LicenseException
       _HResult=-2146232063
       _message=You must have a license to use this ActiveX control.
       HResult=-2146232063
       IsTransient=false
       Message=You must have a license to use this ActiveX control.
       Source=System.Windows.Forms
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
            at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
            at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
            at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
            at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
       InnerException:
```

Then we wrote a Windows Forms application, in the beginning we did excatly the same with WPF demo, reference the two DLLs to project, and even the result is the same. It only can show window in our develpment machine, cannot run on clean Test Machine.

So we followed some steps on MSDN, add the ActiveX control (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msmapi32.ocx`) to Visual Studio Toolbox, and drag them to the surface, and it works very well on Test Machine.

The last try by us is, follow the Windows Forms demo did, we intended to add the ocx to toolbox, but the Visual Studio said **it is successfully added to toolbox, but it is not enabled in the active designer due to incompatible with the current designer and .NET framework version (VS2012/.NET 4.0/WPF)**.

We don'n know what's the reason the demo window thrown exception when parse XAML in Test Machine, **it seems we need a license, but does it need a license???**

We tried to achieve it follow Windows Forms demo did, but we even cannot add the ocx to toolbox.

So, if you have some advices towards below questions or any of them, please feel free to let us know:

- Where does the `msmapi32.ocx` come from? Does any windows machine has it or only after installed something. *By the way, we also tried to install Office 2013 on our Test Machine, it sitll the same exception thrown.*
- We know our ocx version is 6.0, which released at 2000. So if we would like to use it in our WPF application, any suggestions?
- What factors can affect this? *we searched the Dev and Test machine, both have the ocx in the folder, and both registry have the MSAPI related item (and the Windows Forms works very well).*
- So if above questions can be answered, it can help us a lot. From your experience, how can you achieve this feature using WPF, using the native API provided by .NET or some else 3rd party control/plugin? In fact our requirement is so eary that user send feedback to some fixed address. That's all we need to do.

Very appreciate if you have some thoughts about our question, and feel free to ask us questions which puzzled you.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need the two-by-four applied: *you need to purchase a license*.  VB6 is still available through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: @HansPassant Then why at my Development machine, application works well? And I don't understand the component needs License?

Answer (score 0):

My post is not an answer to your questions, but provides a solution (if you like it).
In the past I've used this class (mapi compliant).
This class doesn't use native `SmtpClient` class (that sends an email but doesn't interact with your default mailing app) but is able to invoke your email application and popup email window (filled with every detail you need) so your customer can modify it as needed.
More, email sent remains is "sent email" folder...

```
enum HowTo { MAPI_ORIG = 0, MAPI_TO, MAPI_CC, MAPI_BCC };

public class MAPI
{
    [DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
    static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr sess, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class MapiMessage
    {
        public int reserved;
        public string subject;
        public string noteText;
        public string messageType;
        public string dateReceived;
        public string conversationID;
        public int flags;
        public IntPtr originator;
        public int recipCount;
        public IntPtr recips;
        public int fileCount;
        public IntPtr files;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class MapiFileDesc
    {
        public int reserved;
        public int flags;
        public int position;
        public string path;
        public string name;
        public IntPtr type;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class MapiRecipDesc
    {
        public int reserved;
        public int recipClass;
        public string name;
        public string address;
        public int eIDSize;
        public IntPtr entryID;
    }

    List<MapiRecipDesc> m_recipients = new List<MapiRecipDesc>();
    List<string> m_attachments = new List<string>();
    private int m_lastError = 0;
    private const int MAPI_LOGON_UI = 0x00000001;
    private const int MAPI_DIALOG = 0x00000008;
    private const int maxAttachments = 20;

    #region Private methods
    private bool AddRecipients(HowTo howTo, params string[] emails)
    {
        bool ret = true;
        foreach (string email in emails)
        {
            try
            {
                MapiRecipDesc recipient = new MapiRecipDesc();

                recipient.recipClass = (int)howTo;
                recipient.name = email;
                m_recipients.Add(recipient);
            }
            catch { ret = false; }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    private int SendMail(string strSubject, string strBody, int how)
    {
        MapiMessage msg = new MapiMessage();
        msg.subject = strSubject;
        msg.noteText = strBody;

        msg.recips = GetRecipients(out msg.recipCount);
        msg.files = GetAttachments(out msg.fileCount);

        m_lastError = MAPISendMail(new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0), msg, how, 0);
        if (m_lastError > 1)
            MessageBox.Show("MAPISendMail failed! " + LastError, "MAPISendMail");

        Cleanup(ref msg);
        return m_lastError;
    }
    private IntPtr GetRecipients(out int recipCount)
    {
        recipCount = 0;
        if (m_recipients.Count == 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiRecipDesc));
        IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(m_recipients.Count * size);

        int ptr = (int)intPtr;
        foreach (MapiRecipDesc mapiDesc in m_recipients)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mapiDesc, (IntPtr)ptr, false);
            ptr += size;
        }

        recipCount = m_recipients.Count;
        return intPtr;
    }
    private IntPtr GetAttachments(out int fileCount)
    {
        fileCount = 0;
        if (m_attachments == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        if ((m_attachments.Count <= 0) || (m_attachments.Count > maxAttachments))
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiFileDesc));
        IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(m_attachments.Count * size);

        MapiFileDesc mapiFileDesc = new MapiFileDesc();
        mapiFileDesc.position = -1;
        int ptr = (int)intPtr;

        foreach (string strAttachment in m_attachments)
        {
            mapiFileDesc.name = Path.GetFileName(strAttachment);
            mapiFileDesc.path = strAttachment;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mapiFileDesc, (IntPtr)ptr, false);
            ptr += size;
        }

        fileCount = m_attachments.Count;
        return intPtr;
    }
    private void Cleanup(ref MapiMessage msg)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiRecipDesc));
        int ptr = 0;

        if (msg.recips != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ptr = (int)msg.recips;
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.recipCount; i++)
            {
                Marshal.DestroyStructure((IntPtr)ptr, typeof(MapiRecipDesc));
                ptr += size;
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msg.recips);
        }

        if (msg.files != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiFileDesc));

            ptr = (int)msg.files;
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.fileCount; i++)
            {
                Marshal.DestroyStructure((IntPtr)ptr, typeof(MapiFileDesc));
                ptr += size;
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msg.files);
        }

        m_recipients.Clear();
        m_attachments.Clear();
        m_lastError = 0;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    public bool AddTo(params string[] emails)
    {
        return AddRecipients(HowTo.MAPI_TO, emails);
    }
    public bool AddCC(params string[] emails)
    {
        return AddRecipients(HowTo.MAPI_CC, emails);
    }
    public bool AddBCC(params string[] emails)
    {
        return AddRecipients(HowTo.MAPI_BCC, emails);
    }
    public void AddAttachment(string strAttachmentFileName)
    {
        m_attachments.Add(strAttachmentFileName);
    }

    public int SendMailPopup(string strSubject, string strBody)
    {
        return SendMail(strSubject, strBody, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG);
    }
    public int SendMailDirect(string strSubject, string strBody)
    {
        return SendMail(strSubject, strBody, MAPI_LOGON_UI);
    }

    public string LastError
    {
        get
        {
            switch (m_lastError)
            {
                case 0: return "OK";
                case 1: return "User abort [1]";
                case 2: return "General MAPI failure [2]";
                case 3: return "MAPI login failure [3]";
                case 4: return "Disk full [4]";
                case 5: return "Insufficient memory [5]";
                case 6: return "Access denied [6]";
                case 7: return "-unknown- [7]";
                case 8: return "Too many sessions [8]";
                case 9: return "Too many files were specified [9]";
                case 10: return "Too many recipients were specified [10]";
                case 11: return "A specified attachment was not found [11]";
                case 12: return "Attachment open failure [12]";
                case 13: return "Attachment write failure [13]";
                case 14: return "Unknown recipient [14]";
                case 15: return "Bad recipient type [15]";
                case 16: return "No messages [16]";
                case 17: return "Invalid message [17]";
                case 18: return "Text too large [18]";
                case 19: return "Invalid session [19]";
                case 20: return "Type not supported [20]";
                case 21: return "A recipient was specified ambiguously [21]";
                case 22: return "Message in use [22]";
                case 23: return "Network failure [23]";
                case 24: return "Invalid edit fields [24]";
                case 25: return "Invalid recipients [25]";
                case 26: return "Not supported [26]";
                default: return String.Format("MAPI error [{0}]", m_lastError);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try registering the ocx? (Make sure that a newer ocx is not already registered)

I had used native .NET APIs to send mails in the past. Here is a code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
      ///Method to Send an Email informing interested parties about the status of data extraction. 
      /// INPUTS : int iProcessIsSuccess : int informing about the success of the process. -1 means failure, 0 means partial success, 1 means success. 
      ///          string szLogDataToBeSent :  Log data to be sent incase process not successful.
      /// OUTPUTS : bool. True if success, else false.
      /// </summary>
      public bool SendEmailNotification(string szEmailAddressFileName, int iProcessIsSuccess, string szLogDataToBeSent)
      {
         bool bSuccess = false;

         //the the SMTP host.
         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

         //SMTP Server
         client.Host = CommonVariables.EMAIL_SMTP_SERVER;

         //SMTP Credentials
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CommonVariables.EMAIL_USERNAME, CommonVariables.EMAIL_PASSWORD);

         //Creating a new mail.
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

         //Filling 'From' Tab.
         mail.From = new MailAddress(CommonVariables.EMAIL_SENDERS_ADDRESS, CommonVariables.EMAIL_SENDERS_NAME);

         //Filling 'To' tab.
         List<EmailAddress> EmailAddressList = new List<EmailAddress>();
         try
         {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(szEmailAddressFileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
               XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EmailAddress>));
                EmailAddressList = xs.Deserialize(fs) as List<EmailAddress>;
            }

            foreach (EmailAddress addr in EmailAddressList)
            {
               mail.To.Add(addr.RecepientEmailAddress);
            }
         }
         catch(Exception Ex)
         {
            mail.To.Add("somedefaultemail@companyname.com");
         }

         //Filling mail body.
         string szMailBody = "";
         string szMailSubject = "";

         if (1 == iProcessIsSuccess) //Success
         {
            szMailSubject = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_SUBJECT_BOILER_PLATE, "a SUCCESS");
            szMailBody = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_BODY_BOILER_PLATE, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), Environment.MachineName);
            szMailBody += "\r\n" + szMailSubject + "\r\n";

         }
         else if (0 == iProcessIsSuccess) //Partially Success
         {
            szMailSubject = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_SUBJECT_BOILER_PLATE, "a PARTIAL SUCCESS"); ;
            szMailBody = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_BODY_BOILER_PLATE, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), Environment.MachineName);
            szMailBody += "\r\n"+ szMailSubject + "\r\n";
            szMailBody += "\r\n" + "The Log data is as follows:\r\n";
            szMailBody += szLogDataToBeSent;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
         }
         else //Failed
         {
            szMailSubject = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_SUBJECT_BOILER_PLATE, "a FAILURE"); ;
            szMailBody = String.Format(CommonVariables.EMAIL_BODY_BOILER_PLATE, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), Environment.MachineName);
            szMailBody += "\r\n" + szMailSubject + "\r\n";
            szMailBody += "\r\n" + "The Log data is as follows:\r\n";
            szMailBody += szLogDataToBeSent;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
         }

         mail.Body = szMailBody;

         mail.Subject = szMailSubject;

         //Send Email.
         try
         {
            client.Send(mail);
            bSuccess = true;
         }
         catch (Exception Ex)
         {
            bSuccess = false;
         }

         // Clean up.
         mail.Dispose();


         return bSuccess;

      }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's the meaning: **Make sure that a newer ocx is not already registered**, I know less about ActiveX.

Comment: @JerryBian whenever you register an OCX, it makes an entry in registry about the classes it contains the exact location of the dll. Now if you register the same classes from multiple ocxs or same ocx from different places on the disk, the last one to get register will override the entries from all previous registration. This means that only one dll can register a given dll at a time. Since you mentioned that the ocx you have is pretty old, I just cautioned you to against registering the ocx on machines with the newer version of that dll if they are available.